# Нужна помощь с выборкой из БД в sqlite3 на python

Tags: python, sqlite3

Проблема в том что я не могу разобраться как вытаскивать данные из таблицы. Мне кажется что я уже весь интернет перерыл. Вот код

```
con = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, status INTEGER)')

cur.execute('SELECT id, name, status FROM users')

#Проблема здесь
id, name, status = cur.fetchall()
print(id)
print(name)
print(status)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой вариант вывода:

```
from sqlite3 import *


def sql_connection():
    try:
        con = connect('Joinprimer.db')  #название вашей БД
        return con
    except Error:
        print(Error)


con = sql_connection()
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM TableA;") #Название вашей таблицы
results = cur.fetchall()
for a,b,c,d in results:     #кол-во переменных в зависимости от кол-ва столбцов в таблице
    print(a,b,c,d)
con.commit()

# Empl (Номер, Фамилия, Возраст, Стаж, Зарплата) - a,b,c,d,e - пример
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример:

```
cur.execute('SELECT id, name, status FROM users')

for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)
```